# Selecting shared file via SkyDrive FilePicker?

Tags: windows-8, live, onedrive

Does anyone know if it's possible to pick a file that's been shared with me from someone else's SkyDrive in my SkyDrive file picker in Windows 8? when I invoke the file picker in an app, it appears that I can choose to pick from the SkyDrive app but I think I can only choose files in my own SkyDrive and not files that have been shared with me from others'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you cannot yet. Hopefully this will come along in a later version of the SkyDrive app for Windows 8.